# Android Mediastore and External Database

Tags: android, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm new to android app development. I want to create a video list that will be populated by an external database phpmyadmin and mysql. Can I use the mediastore class for this?

Answer (score 1):

The MediaStore class contains information about the built-in MediaStore content provider. You may or may not be able to use MediaStore, depending on what exactly you're trying to do.

I feel uncomfortable answering in any more detail, because it's not obvious to me what you're trying to do. Give a brief overview of what your app is trying to do.

Comment: I'm currently trying to build an app that will play videos that will be stored in phpmyadmin. when the app is started i would like it to query the database for all videos and populate the list view screen for which i hope that if a click on the video thumbnail that it will bring to the play video screen